# How to design a table in Cassandra with event date and four column to filter

Tags: cassandra

Here is my case: I have a flow of csv which represent 1-2 millions of event per day that has to be filtered on two variables : date range and one of four different columns. My only constraint is that data has to be stored on a single server.

I'm an advanced user on database and I had some interesting results on Postgres and Mysql with partition per day and index on the four columns. I did some tries on Cassandra but I was quite disappointed with the performance. Can Cassandra be competitive on a single server to do this kind of filtering compared to a database ? I tried different table structure without significant performance result. Do you have any recommendation ?

Comment: If you have a requirement to store the data on a single machine, then why would you choose Cassandra over the alternatives you mentioned? And what was the design of the table that you benchmarked Cassandra with?

Comment: I will choose the most performant solution. My conclusion so far is that Cassandra on a single server is an interesting solution when the filtering is done on one or two dimension. The performance is bad if the filtering can be done on serval columns. However I'm not an advanced Cassandra user and before concluding anything, I prefer to check here if I missed something.

Comment: You might already know that partition key is must to query on Cassandra tables and Order of your predicates in where should match the order you specified for Clustering columns in your table definition. You can also create Secondary indexes. But, consider using them along with your partition key in you where clause